# PrimeNG pagination showning all data on one page

Tags: angular, primeng

I want to use primeng pagination for my app. I refer [this  doc](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/page) . But it's not working. I have 10 records and I gave rows value 2 but it's shwoing all 10 records on one page.

HTML code

```
<div class="p-grid">
 <div class="p-col">
  <p-table #table [value]="coins" [paginator]="true" [rows]="2" [responsive]="true">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body">
    <tr *ngFor="let coin of coins">
      <td>{{coin.id}}</td>
      <td>{{coin.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

TestComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CryptoService } from 'src/app/services/crypto.service';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-test',
 templateUrl: './test.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  coins = [];
  constructor(private cryptoservice: CryptoService)
  {
    this.coins = cryptoservice.getMyItems();
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

CrptoService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CryptoService {

 coins= [
   {id: 1, name: 'BTC'},
   {id: 2, name: 'XRP'},
   {id: 3, name: 'SSS'},
   {id: 4, name: 'ERT'},
   {id: 5, name: 'KKK'},
   {id: 6, name: 'LLL'},
   {id: 7, name: 'III'},
   {id: 8, name: 'OOO'},
   {id: 9, name: 'PPPP'}
 ];

 constructor() { }

 getMyItems()
 {
   return this.coins;
 }
}
```

I'm getting output like this.
[image]

Comment: You are not doing this as it is in provided by you example. Please try to use columns and rowData

Comment: You're using [value]="coins" and *ngFor="let coin of coins". So you're supplying the data 2 times that way.
In the body template you should use the "let-rowData" as in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your body template with the line below:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table template body is implemented wrongly.

You should implement it in this way as you are not passing `[cols]` (columns) dynamically:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-coin>
    <tr>
       <td>{{coin.id}}</td>
       <td>{{coin.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```